# Matlab Neural Network Advice

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am working currently on a project to optimize heater performance using MATLAB neural network tool, I read the manuals and got the guidance from MATLAB manual.
I have configured the network and tested it, what I need is two points:
1. Am I on the right track? is my network correct? I need an expert advise
2. I need to (Optimize) the performance of the heater, I have defined my function but I don't have a clue how to integrate the network in the optimization of the function.
my network is as follows
3 inputs x1 x2 x3
one out put

```
load input1
load input2
load input3

x1= importdata('input1.txt');  (similar the other inputs and output)
[x1n,x1min,x1max]=norm_nn(x1);  ( I worte my own normalization function)
IN=[x1n x2n x3n]';
OUT=[y1n]';
INTRAIN = IN(:,1:1307);
OUTTRAIN = OUT(:,1:1307);
INTEST =IN(:,1308 : 1634);
OUTTEST = OUT(:,1308:1634);
NETWORKNet1 = newff(IN,OUT,[20 20 20], {'tansig' 'tansig' }, 'trainbr');
net = init (NETWORKNet1);
NETWORKNet1 = trainbr(NETWORKNet1,INTRAIN,OUTTRAIN);
YtestNwt1 = sim(NETWORKNet1,INTEST);
y1testd=denorm_nn7(YtestNet1(1,:),y1min,y1max);
e1=er8(y1testd,y1(1308:1634));
save Net1
```

I have used (1634 data points and divided it for training  (80%) and test (20%))

Answer (score 1):

Here is some advice:

(A) Use feedforwardnet as newff is deprecated

(B) Plot the training, test data and the network result to make it easier to visualize what's going on.

(C) By writing [20 20 20] your network has 3 hidden layers. The vast majority of problems require only 1 hidden layer. Only if all other avenues have been exhausted should you move to multiple hidden layers.

(D) Test the network (ie, the `sim` command) on the training data first. This is an 'easy' test for a neural network and should be working first before you move on. Then you can test it with the test data (which the network was not trained on). This will show if the network has generalized the shape of the data it is trying to learn.
Validation is also another important factor which helps the network to generalize. If you look at the matlab neural network training window (nntraintool) and click 'performance', one of the graphs should be labelled 'validation'.

Regarding your specific questions:
1. Is my network correct? - difficult to say without seeing the dataset.
2. Optimizing performance of the heater - on a simple level you would have a single output neuron, a number between 0 and 1 which denotes heater performance. The input neurons then contain any other parameters involved.
But now, the network can only predict what the performance will be, given any combination of inputs. It won't be able to tell you which inputs will give you maxmimum output. For only 3 inputs, with low resolution / granularity, you could try an exhaustive / brute force search. Otherwise, look into genetic algorithms to quickly find a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I will use genetic algorithms for the optimization part